# PredicateBuilder Where List inside List with C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, predicatebuilder

I have a problem with PredicateBuilder Class.

I have a 3 class like.

```
public class A
{
  public int val1 {get;set;}
  public int val2 {get;set;}
  public List<B> listb {get;set;}
}

public class B
{
  public int val3 {get;set;}
  public int val4 {get;set;}
  public List<C> listc {get;set;}
}
```

how can i search val3 in B class
I need a search like :

```
var query = PredicateBuilder.True<A>();
query = query.And(x => x.listb.Where(b=> b.val3 == 1);
```

Comment: I am getting error.
cannot implicitly convert type "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<A> to bool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply replace `.Where()` with `.Any()` to create a true/false boolean condition:

```
query.And(x => x.listb.Any(b => b.val3 == 1));
```

This will return all `A` records where any item in `listb` contains a `val3` of `1`.  If you only want `A` records where ***all*** items in `listb` match the condition, use `.All()`:

```
query.And(x => x.listb.All(b => b.val3 == 1));
```